# How to select a rectangular range in VIM?

Tags: vim, selection

Assuming I have a text like

```
abc121313131abc
abc13153545464abc
abc4325435345abc
abc343535353535353abc
```

I want to select the  `abc`s in front of the 4 lines.How can I do this?

Answer (score 75, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>V</kbd> will allow you to visually select a rectangular block. Under Windows, try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Q</kbd> instead.

Comment: `ctrl+v` worked in windows for me

Comment: That's actually `Ctrl+Shift+V`, since it's capital "V".