# How can I select a vertical column of text in GVim?

Tags: gvim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to select a rectangular range in VIM?](https://superuser.com/questions/208852/how-to-select-a-rectangular-range-in-vim)

I am very new to Vim, I am using gVim for Windows...

Is it possible to select a "vertical column" of text? If I wanted to select the text in the red rectangle below how would I go about this?

[image]